# Can i use MyEclipse IDE instead of Eclipse IDE (Eclipse for Testers) for using testing with Selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am new with Selenium and having java development experience.

I have installed Selenium IDE as plugin with Firefox.

I have MyEclipse IDE. Should i download another Eclipse IDE for using testing with Selenium Webdriver. If yes then please suggest which version of Eclipse would be best suited for my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn the basics of selenium IDE you better play around with selenium IDE in Firefox.
If you have knowledge in any of the programming languages like Java, python, ruby, c#, PHP
You can use Selenium Webdriver along with any of the mentioned programming languages to write automation testing scripts.

COming to eclipse IDE,when you start using Selenium Webdriver, you need to use Eclipse IDE. other wise if you use Selneium IDE in Firefox, there is no need to use Eclipse as Selenium IDE is just a record and playback tool(also you can add and modify the selenium commands).

you can use Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers present in the below link.
http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have java experience. Can i use MyEclipse IDE instead of Eclipse IDE with Selenium Webdriver. or should i download Eclipse IDE?

Comment: You can use MyEclipse. Selenium Webdriver is a jar file which should be added to your libraries related to your java-selenium project.
Selenium Webdriver is nothing but, you will be using the features of a just another java class called WebDriver. If you have good knowledge in Java. You can simply go ahead. You can use MyEclipse.

Answer (score 0):

No. Perhaps we can not use MyEclipse with selenium. Furthermore IDE is not relevant alternate to Eclipse.